# The platform’s statistics on how long users use resources are wrong. What could be the problem?

Tags: database, statistics

A platform's services use cloud services, which count the user's usage time.Users may not use it continuously. They may continue to use it after shutting it down for a certain period of time. Occasionally, the unused period will also be counted in the statistics. What is the problem? Is it a database update problem or a data transmission problem or something else?

I haven't reproduced it yet.I want to solve this problem and want to know the specific reasons.